# A function bound to multiple buttons internal variables are being shared

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am binding an ajax calls to multiple buttons that are unique based on attached data attributes.

Now the internal variables of the function are shared. So, if I click on multiple buttons (i.e. before previous ajax requests have completed) the variables are over-writing each other....

```
$('.btn-merge').click(function(){
    $this = $( this );
    pid = $this.data('pid');
    cid = $this.data('cid');
    $this.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning').prop('disabled',true).closest('li.suggestions').addClass('waiting-merge');
    putData = {
        catalogId : cid,
        productId : pid
    };
    $.post("///url///",putData,function (returnData){
        if (returnData === 'true'){
            suggestion = $this.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-success').closest('li.suggestions').removeClass('waiting-merge').addClass('success-merge').appendTo('ul.catalog-products').slideDown();

            suggestion.find('.btn-unmerge').data('cid',cid).show().prop('disabled',false).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');

            suggestion.find('.suggestion-cid').text('Catalog ID:'+cid);
        }
        else 
            $this.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-danger').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using global variables.

Inside your callback function, prefix variables with `var` to make sure they don't [leak the scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: That solved my issue but i dont understand why ??? ... the whole thing is in a self invoking anonymous function

Comment: Read more about variable scope in Javascript. In general, when you don't declare your variables with `var` is equivalent to declaring `window.var`.